# Trouble importing java class with JPype

Tags: python, lucene, jpype

I try desperately to import a java class in python using JPype.

It works fine most of the time, but for some reasons not for this import :

```
from org.apache.lucene.analysis.tokenattributes import OffsetAttribute
```

The debugger returns:

> AttributeError: type object
> 'org.apache.lucene.analysis.tokenattributes.OffsetA' has no attribute
> 'loader'

It seems the import path is truncated as if it were too long.

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution.

It seems this bug is already known:
https://github.com/jpype-project/jpype/issues/838

Here is the workaround I used to import my class:

```
OffsetAttribute = jpype.JClass('org.apache.lucene.analysis.tokenattributes.OffsetAttribute')
```